# Reading a large text file in variable sized chunks with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a large text file (~6GB) that contains multiple pages. Pages are separated by a form-feed character ( `^L` ).

Each page has a header and then a table of fixed-width data. I want to use the Pandas [read_fwf()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) function that accepts a [chunksize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#iteration) argument, but the chunksize isn't a fixed number of lines in my case.

For reference, an example file looks like this and has thousands of pages:

```
Company ID 1                 Document Title                      YY-MM-DD
                            Document SubTitle                    HH:MM:SS

Unit Name: First Unit                                           Page:   1

Col1      Col2           Col3                  Col4           Col5   Col6
Col6      Col7                                 Col8           Col9

Data-111  ABC            DEF                   XYZ            MNOP   123A
Data-111  Description of data-111 in this col  111xx          BlahBlahBla
Data-222  ABC            DEF                   XYZ            MNOP   123A
Data-222  Description of data-222 in this col  222xx          BlahBlahBla
Data-333  ABC            DEF                   XYZ            MNOP   123A
Data-333  Description of data-333 in this col  333xx          BlahBlahBla^L

Company ID 2                 Document Title                      YY-MM-DD
                            Document SubTitle                    HH:MM:SS

Unit Name: Second Unit                                          Page:   2

Col1      Col2           Col3                  Col4           Col5   Col6
Col6      Col7                                 Col8           Col9

Data-444  ABC            DEF                   XYZ            MNOP   123A
Data-444  Description of data-444 in this col  111xx          BlahBlahBla^L

Company ID 3                 Document Title                      YY-MM-DD
                            Document SubTitle                    HH:MM:SS

Unit Name: Third Unit                                           Page:   3

Col1      Col2           Col3                  Col4           Col5   Col6
Col6      Col7                                 Col8           Col9

Data-555  ABC            DEF                   XYZ            MNOP   123A
Data-555  Description of data-555 in this col  111xx          BlahBlahBla
Data-666  ABC            DEF                   XYZ            MNOP   666N
Data-666  Description of data-666 in this col  111xx          BlahBlahBla^L
```

As you can see, pages are separated by ^L and each page has a variable number of rows (starting with Data-xxx). Page 1 has 6 rows of data, Page 2 has 2 rows of data and Page 3 has 4 rows of data.

I want to read each page with `read_fwf()` and get a dataframe. Is it possible to do this without having to iterate over the file line by line?

Comment: Since read_fwf() accepts files or buffers, I'd write a generator, that yields each page as a buffer and feed that info read_fwf(). This is some kind of iteration over the whole file, but so would using chunksize be as well.

Comment: @576i didn't have any luck with read_fwf() since the data is split over multiple rows (half the columns of a record on Row 1, half the columns on Row 2). So, I just wrote a script that reads the file line by line, and a generator yields pages. Then a function parses one page at a time.